# SSL certificate for IIS

Tags: iis, ssl, https

I am on windows server 2003 and I have a CGI site that uses a DLL file called account.dll

I want to secure call to one page only so I followed the steps about adding new certificate and I have only the option "send it later" active.

so I have now a text file contain the certificate request, my question:

- How I can create a certificate from that request text file ?
- I know that to secure one page I right click on account.dll and choose properties for that file but what is the options I must use to configure this file **alone** for HTTPS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text file you created with the New Certificate wizard is the certificate request. You need to either ship it to a third-party CA to have a certificate created, or put up your own CA and sign it yourself. You'll have to decide which is appropriate based on whether or not your client computers will be alright with an untrusted CA (i.e. a home-grown CA is alright for internal-use sites, typically) or if you need the reputation of a public CA (i.e. business with J. Random Internet user, etc). A third-party CA will normally have you paste the contents of the certificate request file into a form field.

To force HTTPS connections for a specific file in an IIS 6 site, go to the "Properties" sheet for the file, go to the "Directory" tab, "Edit" under "Secure Communications" (which will become available only after you have a certificate installed). In the dialog that opens, tick the "Require Secure Channel (SSL)" box and SSL will be required to access that file.

Comment: it is online shopping site, can godaddy.com give me that certificate ?

thanks alot

Comment: please also tell me how to sign it myself for testing purpose

thanks

Comment: Yes, GoDaddy can issue you a certificate. You can also use one of these tutorials to create a self-signed certificate: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate.html

Comment: Update:
I can access the site using SSL like this:

https://mysite.com/securedpage

but I can not access the site like this
https://secure.mysite.com/securedpage

how to make the above path work ?

thanks

Comment: do I need to register the domain secure.mysite.com first ?

Comment: @user49022: "secure.mysite.com" is a third-level domain, so you don't need to "register" it with any registrar. You just need to create the "A" record for the "secure" host in the "mysite.com" DNS zone. (Where / how you manage your DNS will be determined by who is hosting it...)